# Python: unexpected error when indent seems to be correct in IDLE?

Tags: python, python-3.4

My code is acting up.. The line that says "replace = line[start:end]" returns an unexpected indent error, but I don't understand why?

I'm using python 3.4, and it made sense to keep it in the same suite as the other code. Can someone elaborate on why idle would return this error? Thank you.

full code:

```
import random
line = random.choice(open('madlibs.txt').readlines())

print(line)

inputStore = [""]
end = 0
repetitions = line.count('{')
for i in range(repetitions):
    start = line.find('{', end)+ 1
    end = line.find('}', start)
    replace = line[start:end]
    inputStore.append(replace)
```

Comment: What is that `return` doing there?

Comment: tabs and not spaces ? Although as @AshwiniChaudhary says - the return is odd too

Comment: Sounds like you are mixing tabs and spaces. Make sure to ONLY use spaces (4 per indentation level) to indent. Python considers a tab to be 8 spaces wide, so it's easy to mess things up when mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: `return` does not have to be there

Comment: I actually triple checked to make sure that I used spaces instead of tabs. I just checked yet again to make sure that 4 spaces were used. Weird.. I took the return out as well! Made no sense being there, so thank you for catching that.

Comment: @Star Run your script using `-tt`: `python -tt script_name.py` and remove that `return` statement. `return` statements can only be used inside functions.

Comment: @ThiefMaster or only use tabs

Comment: @Star Also can you post the exact error? Python 3 complains quite explicitly when we mix tabs and spaces so my previous suggestion of `-tt` won't help much in Python 3.

Comment: Thank you everyone! @ashwini, What you said to input worked. Can you explain to me how it managed to do what I wanted it to? Thanks!

Comment: I've had similar problems when editing files in more than one editor i.e. Geany/Pycharm as some editors handle the `Tab` key differently. Worth noting.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary does that mean Python 3 turns on `-tt` by default? Or is the behavior somehow different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution, posted by Ashwini Chaudhary worked:

Run your script using -tt: python -tt script_name.py and remove that return statement. return statements can only be used inside functions